# Render SVG with external references to Canvas

Tags: javascript, html, image, canvas, svg

I'm trying to render an SVG to canvas, using a `data: URI` and `canvas.drawImage()`. This works well, except that external images in the SVG are not included on the resulting canvas.

Example HTML ([live jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/ss5bjooj/)):

```
<canvas id="canvas" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
<div id="container">
    <svg id="mySVG" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
      <rect width="150" height="150" fill="rgb(0, 255, 0)" stroke-width="1" stroke="rgb(0, 0, 0)"/>
      <image preserveAspectRatio="none" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/7/70/Example.png" width="80" height="80"></image>
    </svg>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas'),
    ctx = canvas.getContext('2d'),
    svg = document.getElementById('container').innerHTML,
    img = new Image();

img.onload = function () {
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
};
img.src = 'data:image/svg+xml,' + svg;
```

I've tried setting a timeout before calling drawImage, hoping that it would be a synchronization issue, but it did not seem to help. Any ideas?

Comment: Just one. Don't use external images they won't work. You'll need to convert your external images to data URIs

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29975138/how-can-i-get-pngbase64-with-images-inside-of-svg-in-google-charts/30135485

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a canvas issue. It won't work/will look the same even if you are not using the canvas at all and just appending your HTMLImageElement to the DOM. see:

```
    var svg = document.getElementById('container').innerHTML,
    img = new Image();

img.onload = function () {
    document.body.appendChild(img); // img does not contain Wikipedia image
};
img.src = 'data:image/svg+xml,' + svg;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ss5bjooj/2/