# Save svg as png where svg contains images with external reference

Tags: jquery, cross-domain, canvg

I have an SVG with many image tags referring to external image sources(Say from amazon s3 bucket) . I am trying to convert it into png like this

```
canvg(document.getElementById('myCanvas'), svg);
 var imgData = document.getElementById('myCanvas').toDataURL("image/png");
```

I am getting this error **Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to execute 'toDataURL' on 'HTMLCanvasElement': Tainted canvases may not be exported.**

I have changed my s3 bucket settings ([As mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17533888/s3-access-control-allow-origin-header)).
Added this piece of code after canvg function

```
var img = new Image();
    img.setAttribute('crossOrigin', 'anonymous');
    img.src = document.getElementById('myCanvas').value;
```

Even tried iterating over all the image tags and set crossOrigin attribute

Still I am getting the same error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29975138/how-can-i-get-pngbase64-with-images-inside-of-svg-in-google-charts

Comment: Finally I got a solution. I am doing the conversion in server side now (using apache batik transcoder library) No more security errors ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found it better to do the conversion in server side since allowing cross origin in amazon s3 is a security threat and many browsers won't support .toDataUrl even if cross-origin permissions are given.

This is how I am doing the conversion

In client side

```
var s = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(document.getElementById("svg"))
var encodedData = window.btoa(s);
```

And this encoded data is passed to the server side where I do the actual conversion svg to png using batik library

```
BASE64Decoder decoder = new BASE64Decoder();
    byte[] image = decoder.decodeBuffer(encodedData);
    String fileLocation  = "C:\temp";
    String fileName = "New-" + System.currentTimeMillis();
    File file = new File(fileLocation +File.separator+ fileName + ".svg");
    FileOutputStream fop = new FileOutputStream(file);
    if (!file.exists()) {
      file.createNewFile();
    }
    fop.write(image);
    fop.flush();
    fop.close();
    PNGTranscoder transcoder = new PNGTranscoder();
    TranscoderInput tinput = new TranscoderInput(new FileInputStream(fileLocation + File.separator + fileName +".svg"));
    OutputStream ostream = new FileOutputStream(fileLocation + File.separator + fileName +".png");
    TranscoderOutput toutput = new TranscoderOutput(ostream);
    try {
          transcoder.transcode(tinput, toutput);
    } catch (TranscoderException e) { 
          System.out.println("error*");
           e.printStackTrace();
    }
    ostream.close();
```